# Multi region ec2 instance replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Our current server of web application is deployed in Singapore region but as we're going to launch our services in Europe so we want to replicate our ec2 instance in London region so any traffic coming from that region will be served from that instance which will give us low latency. How we can achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should address this using AWS Route 53 routing policies.

Route 53 has 5 different routing policies and you can use one of following two policies in this case.

1. Geolocation routing policy – Use when you want to route traffic based on the location of your users.
2. Latency routing policy – Use when you have resources in multiple locations and you want to route traffic to the resource that provides the best latency.

Since you are looking at a latency based traffic allocation, as the name suggest, you should use Latency routing policy.

For more information about routing policies please refer [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html).

To replicate the EC2 instance to a different region,

- Create a snapshot of your EBS volume.
- Copy the EBS Snapshot to a London Region
- If you are using a custom AMI, you will have to copy the AMI to London region as well
- Launch a new EC2 Instance using the copied snapshot in the London region.

Comment: this is what i was looking for, but can you explain how i can achieve replication?

Comment: but then question is how the deployment works? either i have to pull the latest code on both servers or i have to use jenkin as deployment so that i can pull on all servers one by one.

Comment: Actually that depends on how you do the deliveries. One way is to use Jenkins as you suggested. There are few more effective methodologies described in this thread `https://stackoverflow.com/a/13460809/1844843`

Comment: And of course AWS CodeDeploy service may come in handy.

Comment: @AwnAli Thanks for Accepting the answer. if you find it informative, an upvote would send some love :)